# Is this way for solving convergence valid?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln (x+1)-\ln(x)}{x}$$

***solving:***
$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln ((x+1)/x)}{x}$

$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\sqrt[x]{(1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}}=e}{x}$

$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln e^\frac{1}{x}}{x}$

$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}}$

from last line we can see that the intgral converges...
however the lecturer has written on the test that thr second line is wrong and that "$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\neq$" to the original intgral

I didn't get any points for this particular exercise.

why is the transition in second line is wrong(which is why in his opinion the whole answer is defect)? I've just written the term in another way so I can get 'e' I didn't change it in any way? Have I done something wrong?
The answer is that it is convergnet which is also what I got...

Answer (score 1):

No, your method is not valid because you have essentially claimed that for all $x \in [1, \infty)$, $$\frac{x+1}{x} = e^{1/x}.$$  Although when $x$ is "large," both the LHS and RHS tend to $1$, it is not justified when $x$ is near $1$.  The error occurs when you assert $$(1 + 1/x)^x = e.$$  This is only true as a **limit**.

If, however, you had found a function $g(x) \ge \frac{\log (x+1) - \log x}{x}$ on $[1, \infty)$ such that $$\int_{x=1}^\infty g(x) \, dx < \infty$$ then this would assure convergence of the original integral.

---

Although not in the scope of your question--which merely asks for whether the integral converges--the integral can be evaluated via series expansion about $\infty$:  $$\frac{\log (x+1) - \log x}{x} = x^{-1} \cdot \log (1 + x^{-1}) = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(k-1) x^k}.$$  Therefore $$\int_{x=1}^\infty \frac{\log (x+1) - \log x}{x} \, dx = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \int_{x=1}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^k}{(k-1) x^k} \, dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2}.$$  This sum has value $\pi^2/12$ via an elementary modification of the solution to the Basel problem.

Comment: I think you mean ${} < \infty$ in the last display

Comment: I understand your way of solving this, but why mine is wrong? by second line I mean the term "intgeral ln sqrt...." n\sqrt{somthing}^n cancels each other out. I didn't change anything in the process

Comment: @user6394019 I already explained why your solution is invalid:  your manipulation is not true for **every** $1 \le x < \infty$.  To claim that $(1 + 1/x)^x = e$ is not the same as saying $$\lim_{x \to \infty} (1 + 1/x)^x = e.$$  The first is wrong; the second is right.  In your version, simply substitute $x = 1$.  Then you are saying $2 = e$.  That is plainly false.

Comment: Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your assertion is wrong.
$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{\log(x+1)-\log(x)}{x}\;dx = \frac{\pi^2}{12}
\tag{1}$$
but
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\;dx = 1
\tag{2}$$
As noted, a correct way to solve this would be to show
$$
\frac{\log(x+1)-\log(x)}{x} \le \frac{1}{x^2}
$$
and then use the fact that $(2)$ is finite.